# Gradle "test" task does not fail where it should be

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, gradle, testng

Hello I am new to Gradle. We just switch from Maven to Gradle and I have some difficulties in understanding of Gradle test task.
Here is my class:

```
public class Money   {
private final int amount;
private final String currency;

public Money(int amount, String currency) {
    if (amount < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal amount: [" + amount + "]");
    }
    if (currency == null || currency.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal currency: [" + currency + "]");
    }
    //this.amount = 15;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.currency = currency;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}
}
```

And here is my test (using TestNG):

```
@Test
public class MoneyManyValuesTest {
  public void testConstructor() {
    Money money = new Money(10, "USD");
    assertEquals(money.getAmount(), 10);
    assertEquals(money.getCurrency(), "USD");
    money = new Money(20, "EUR");
    assertEquals(money.getAmount(), 20);
    assertEquals(money.getCurrency(), "EUR");
 }
}
```

When I run test  (with gradle "test" task) everything looks like OK.

But then I want my test to fail, so I tweak last row of my test like this:

```
assertEquals(money.getCurrency(), "EUR want error here");
```

Run gradle "test" again and test still passes with msg:

```
2:40:26 PM: Executing external task 'test'...
money:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
money:processResources UP-TO-DATE
money:classes UP-TO-DATE
money:compileTestJava
money:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
money:testClasses
money:test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

What is going on here?

Here is my build script

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

apply plugin: 'java';
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.3.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.0'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert:1.4'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.1'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
}
```

Comment: Did you instruct Gradle to use TestNG? Did you check out the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) (search for `TestNG`) and the TestNG samples in the full Gradle distro? Did you run the build with `--info` or `--debug` to get more information? Most likely the build isn't executing your tests.

Comment: What does the test report say (in build/report/tests)?

Comment: my gradle.build contains test {useTestNG()}. Somehow it does not see changes in my code and thinks all is UP-TO-DATE

Comment: post your build.gradle file. Are you using plugin java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA. And my IDE saves my source code automatically. I am so accustomed to this feature so I even forgot that IDEA does this for me. 
Looks like whenever I ran Gradle "test" task, IDEA does not saves my source code automaticly. But if I save it manually everything works fine.